# Displaying php sql result using jquery-repeater

Tags: jquery, twig

My SQL RESULT looks like

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    1 => array:3 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "code" => "A"
        "type" => "Main"
        "productcode" => "VW"
        "id" => 203
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▼
        "code" => "B1"
        "type" => "Sub"
        "productcode" => "VW"
        "id" => 203
      ]
      2 => array:4 [▼
        "code" => "B2"
        "type" => "Sub"
        "productcode" => "VW"
        "id" => 203
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    1 => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "code" => "C"
        "type" => "Main"
        "productcode" => "CM"
        "id" => 204
      ]
      1 => array:4 [▼
        "code" => "D1"
        "type" => "Sub"
        "productcode" => "CM"
        "id" => 204
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I have written twig code like this

```
<form class="outer-repeater" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row mb-4 pt-5 justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div data-repeater-list="outer-list">
        <div data-repeater-item>
          {% for value in get_code %}
          {% for numberin in value %}
          {% for info in numberin %}                             
             <div data-repeater-list="outer-list">
              {% if info.type == Main' %}
                <div data-repeater-item>
                    <br/> 
                    MAIN-CODE 
                      <input type="text" name="text-input" value="{{info.qrcode}}"/>
                      <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
                </div>
              </div>   
              {% else if info.type == Sub' %}
                <!-- innner SUB repeater -->
                  <div class="inner-repeater">
                    <div data-repeater-list="inner-list">
                      <div data-repeater-item style="background: #f1f1f1">
                        SUB <input type="text" name="inner-text-input" value="{{info.qrcode}}"/>
                        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add SUB Repeater"/>
                  </div>
                <!-- end inner SUB repeater -->
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
          <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add MAIN REPEATER"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
</form>
```

The expected output I want looks something like this

```
|A| |Delete button|
  |B1| |Delete button|
  |B2| |Delete button|
  |Add Sub Repeater button|
|C| |Delete button|
  |D1| |Delete button|
  |Add Sub Repeater button|

|ADD MAIN REPEATER|
```

Few examples:

1. If A is deleted than all B1 and B2 gets deleted
   2)If B1 delete button is pressed it will remove that element only.
2. If Sub Repeater button is pressed in A then input is seen.
3. First 203 id is printed in twig with both Main and Sub and then 204.

*Do not be worried about productcode in sql result*
*If you have any other way to do that apart from jquery repeater that's fine*

Comment: If your template output is already correct, then why is this tagged with twig?

Comment: It is not giving me proper output. Like sometimes sub repeater does not work and sometimes main repeater.

Comment: This "sub repeater" is all part of a jquery plugin? So it's not twig related at all? Please post the generated template then rather than the twig template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer from php to twig (view)

```
 <form class="outer-repeater">
                                     <div data-repeater-list="group-a">
                                        {% for value in get_code %}
                                                                  
                                        {% for numberin in value %}
                                              {% for keys, info in numberin %}
                                          {% set last_item = numberin|length - 1 %}
                                                {% if info.qtype == 'Main' %}
                                                <div data-repeater-item class="row">
                                                    <div  class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                                                        <label for="name">Main QR</label>
                                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="untyped-input" class="form-control" value="{{info.code}}"/>
                                                    </div>
                          
                                                {% endif %}
                                                  {% if info.qtype == 'Sub'%}
                                                    <div class="inner-repeater mb-4">
                                                        <div data-repeater-list="inner-group" class="inner mb-3">
                                                        {%  if loop.index == 2 %}
                                                            <label>Sub Qrcode no :</label>
                                                          {% endif %}
                                                            <div data-repeater-item class="inner mb-3 row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-10 col-8">
                                                                    <input type="text" name="sub-code" class="inner form-control" value="{{info.code}}"/>
                                                                </div>
                                                                
                                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-4">
                                                                    <div class="d-grid">
                                                                        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" class="btn btn-primary inner" value="Delete"/>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        {% if keys == last_item %}
                                                        <input data-repeater-create type="button" class="btn btn-success inner" value="Add Sub"/>
                                                        {% endif %}
                                                    </div>
                                                  {% endif %}
                                                    {% endfor %} 
                                                         {% endfor %} 
                                                           <div class="col-lg-2 align-self-center">
                                                        <div class="d-grid">
                                                            <input data-repeater-delete type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                  
                                               </div>  
                                       {% endfor %}
                                               
                                            </div>
                                            <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add Repeater"/>
```